# Override fasterxml jackson ObjectMapper used by Spring Integration dsl

Tags: spring, java-8, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Using Transformers.toJson() my json date looks like this:

"createdDate":{"year":2017,"month":"OCTOBER","monthValue":10,"dayOfMonth":25,"hour":7,"minute":57,"second":36,"nano":972000000,"dayOfWeek":"WEDNESDAY","dayOfYear":298,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}}

Here is the outbound ampq configuration:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow outboundCdrRabbitFlowDefinition() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(CHANNEL_NAME)
            .transform(Transformers.toJson())
            .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(new RabbitTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory))
                    .routingKey("routing-key"))
            .get();
}
```

The consumer of the rabbit queue expects the format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

Is there any way i can override the default ObjectMapper used by spring integration?

For example i have the this configuration in my web api config that extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setTimeZone(UTC_TIME_ZONE);
    mapper.setDateFormat(ISO_8601_DATE_FORMAT);
    mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    return mapper;
}

@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper());
    return mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
}

@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
}
```

Is there some way to reuse the objectMapper bean in Spring Integration so the mapping configuration is the same across all my outbound endpoints, web api http or integration ampq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an overloaded version of the `Transformers.toJson()`:

```
Transformers.toJson(new Jackson2JsonObjectMapper(objectMapper))
```